# ComponentArt: How do I DataFromat a ComponentArtGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, componentart

Hi I am trying to make it so that my Datafield, RoutingNumber, can be formated into a string. So that each row of the grid has

http://myurl.com/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=123, where 123 is the Routing Number and " http://myurl.com/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=" is a string/

So far i have this code but it does not seem to work.

```
<ComponentArt:GridColumn FormatString="http://twilio.liquidus.net/handleincomingcall.ashx?call={0}",DataField="RoutingNumber"  HeadingText="URL"   />
```

I have tried just displaying the Routing number without the URL in front and it works just fine. Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: you might want to add the appropriate platform tag (Android etc) to attract the right attention

Comment: Thanks, though im not sure what other tags to use. Its all based in VB, and uses the Componentart kit. Problem is its missing DataFormatString, im looking for the componentart equivalent to that.

Comment: winforms? webforms? Android? Asp?

Comment: Sorry about that just updated my tags. Asp.net